# Downloading maps from soilgrids.org

Tags: download, soilgrids

I would like to download some layers from https://soilgrids.org. One is for example the layer "Sand, 0-5, mean". I get a TIFF format which is missing spatial reference. Am I doing something wrong?

I downloaded some layers a few weeks ago on the old version of the website and these included the spatial reference.

Comment: Did you get also a .vrt file with your download https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#What_do_the_filename_codes_mean?

Comment: No, I did not..

Comment: At least https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/recent/sand/sand_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-001-020/tileSG-001-020_2-3.tif is a georeferenced GeoTIFF.

Comment: When I try to add this to ArcMap, it still tells me it is missing spatial reference. How is this possible?

Comment: Ask from your ESRI support. I add some more information as an answer even it does not solve your problem but there is not enough room in this comment box. Send the gdalinfo report as an annex to your support channel.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange. Note in the FAQ [the section on the CRS](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_the_Homolosine_projection). It could be that the software you use is not able to use this CRS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open SoilGrids files in ArcGIS, just define the projection as "World_Goode_Homolosine_Land"..your tiles will appear automatically in the right location, then you can change the projection to your preferences.
I just tried this way for 30 tiles and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Wow! This worked! How did you know that it had to be "World_Goode_Holosine_Land"?
You mentioned you did this for 30 tiles... Is there a way to do it in one go for all of them at the same time?

Comment: Yes Juli , you simply create a mosaic dataset and add all your tiles at World_Goode_Homolosine_Land , then export the mosaiced image to a tiff file or whatever format you like. now you are ready to reproject the mosaiced image to any coordinate system. hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

The new files are georeferenced or at least the few files that I tested. For example this

https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/sand/sand_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-001-020/tileSG-001-020_2-3.tif

Gdalinfo report about the file:

```
gdalinfo tileSG-001-020_2-3.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: tileSG-001-020_2-3.tif
Size is 450, 419
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["D_unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["Unknown",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Interrupted Goode Homolosine"]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-10812500.000000000000000,8030500.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (250.000000000000000,-250.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-10812500.000, 8030500.000) ( 91d27'57.72"W, 77d39'25.54"N)
Lower Left  (-10812500.000, 7925750.000) ( 92d 3'14.59"W, 76d12'18.81"N)
Upper Right (-10700000.000, 8030500.000) ( 88d27'38.29"W, 77d39'25.54"N)
Lower Right (-10700000.000, 7925750.000) ( 89d15'20.66"W, 76d12'18.81"N)
Center      (-10756250.000, 7978125.000) ( 90d19'43.30"W, 76d55'27.45"N)
Band 1 Block=450x9 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=251.000 Max=451.000
  Minimum=251.000, Maximum=451.000, Mean=334.402, StdDev=33.869
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=451
    STATISTICS_MEAN=334.40173043418
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=251
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=33.868562582089
```

QGIS shows the image and coordinates but says that the CRS is Unknown.

[image: Goode homolosine in QGIS]

If you manage to open the image in ArcMap with help from ESRI support or otherwise, please write the solution as your own answer.

**EDIT**

I tried to open the image with ArcMap 10.8. The image is opened and it shows on the map with correct coordinates but ArcMap does not recognize the CRS and image cannot be reprojected. QGIS and GDAL do much better work because even they do not know any name for the CRS they can still reproject data into other CRS.

Reprojecting with gdalwarp is also a workaround for you. Image warped.tif opens fine with ArcMap. Probably some other target CRS would be better than EPSG:4326.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 tileSG-001-020_2-3.tif warped.tif
```

Note: Tile link updated to new structure

Comment: You should target `gdalinfo` against the `.vrt`, but the result is the same.

Comment: VRT combines the directory of individual tiff files into a virtual mosaic. Gdalinfo against the vrt and against a single image file both work but the commands do not mean the same.

Comment: When I open the image, it is not shown with the correct coordinates (Arc Map 10.7.1). And reprojecting does not solve it.

Comment: What is wrong in the coordinates? Are the corner coordinates wrong `Upper Left  (-10812500.000, 8030500.000) ( 91d27'57.72"W, 77d39'25.54"N)`? What should they be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with ArcGIS 10.3, two days ago I downloaded 30 tiles of mean clay 0-5m and were not rectified.. Alternatively, I did the following steps:

1. create a raster catalogue of your tiles and add the tiff files as raster datasets,
2. right-click on the raster catalogue and select Data -> Mosiac raster catalogue. you'll get one mosaiced image yet not rectified.
3. rectify the mosaiced image manually using 2nd order polynomial.

it's not a perfect solution but it helps until the WCS is published.